Trajectories of electrons in an electric field
I will start by quoting the exact statement of NCERT:

Are the paths of electrons straight lines between successive collisions (with the positive ions of the metal) in the:
(1) absence of electric field?
(2) presence of electric field?
Answer: In the absence of electric field, the paths are straight lines; in the presence of electric field, the parts are, in general, curved.

So my doubt lies in the second part where it states that electrons travel in curved paths in the presence of an electric field. I know that in the presence of an electric field, electrons move with drift velocity which I think ought to be straight. In order for them to move in curved paths, there needs to be magnetic field but I don't think one exists there. Please clarify.

JJ Thompson showed that an electric field can deflect the path of an electron.

@JonCuster Can you elaborate as of for WHY?

You can show the path curves with the vacuum tube in the picture from https://virtuelle-experimente.de/en/e-feld/hypothesen/versuchsaufbau.php. If you turn up the voltage between the capacitor plates, the beam curves.

On the other hand, the trajectory can be straight. It is kind of like throwing a rock. If you throw it sideways, the trajectory curves downward. If you throw it straight up or down, the trajectory is a straight line.
This is used in particle accelerators to make them go faster. The accelerator is usually a ring with a short straight section where the acceleration happens. The field points in the direction the electrons are moving.  Accelerator Science: Why RF?

This answer was so much fun to read and I got my doubts clarified as well. I very much appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

It's like the problem of falling in a uniform gravitational field. If you start in the direction straight up or down, then the path is straight. If you start in any other direction then the path is a parabola.
